# Listing and hooking of functions of an app

Tags: android, xposed

I have the following issue. I need to hook a method of an app for monitoring. The issue is that I'm not allowed to change its source code except for including a library and some sort of initialization maybe. So the only options seemed to be Frida and Xposed at first sight, which would require a rooted phone. Another no-go in my case. After a few hours of research, I found a great variant of xposed that seems to be for local apps - the whale framework ( https://github.com/asLody/whale ). It seems to be used like xposed in a similar way.

The only issue I have is that I have no clue on how to use it and the typical examples as listed in the xposed tutorial ( https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial ) cannot be used right away. In particular, I'm looking at "implements IXposedHookLoadPackage" and lpparam.*

Does anyone has an idea on how to use it maybe?

Comment: Frida only need a rooted device if you run the frida executable standalone on the device. If you modify the app and add the "frida-gadget" ([Frida embedded mode](https://frida.re/docs/modes/#embedded)) to the app you don't need a rooted device.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, after hours of research, I was able to find a tutorial on how to use the Whale Framework. If you don't speak Chinese, use Google Translator. After performing the steps described there and based on the provided code, it works great. It let's one make use of the huge resources of Xposed modules for the own, local app to change functionality without root requirements like it is required for my monitoring purposes.

https://blog.csdn.net/tianseyiwan008/article/details/97522266

Notice: A similar way is AspectJ, but Xposed is far more straight forward in my opinion.

Comment: In your question you stated that `rooting the phone is a no-go` for you. As Xposed requires root an Xposed based solution can not be the answer to your question.